# Click element if it does not contain table jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var SELECTOR = 'span.title';
horseman
    .open(url)
    .evaluate(function(selector){
        var els = $(selector);
        $.each(els, function(i, el){
            var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
            event.initEvent('click', true, true);
            el.dispatchEvent(event);
        });
    }, SELECTOR)
    .then(//other stuff)
    .finally(//other stuff
```

The above code clicks on all the span.title elements it finds on a site. However I only want to click on the ones which **do not** contain a certain element within them, such as a table, then click on it, not sure how to go about this?

Comment: It's hard to understand that actual issue. Can you supply the actual html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Thanks @epascarello for your suggestion first of all!

The only change required was to `var SELECTOR`

Now it looks like this

`var SELECTOR = 'span.title:not(:has(table))';`

This will look for each `span.title` element but it contains a table, then it will **NOT** click it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```js
var selector = "span.title"

, not = function() {
  return !this.querySelectorAll("table").length
};

$(selector).filter(not).css("color", "green")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<span class="title">
  <table><tbody><tr><td>table</td></tr></tbody></table>
</span>
<span class="title">not table</span>
```